# Dynamically create fields in graphql query?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, relaymodern

So in the below example, I want to change stat to a variable, but it appears that variables are not allowed as field names?  Is there a way to work around this?

```
query={graphql`
              query PlayerQuery($condition:GamelogCondition!, $stat:String!) {
                   allGamelogs(condition:$condition){
                        nodes{
                          gameDate
                          stat
                        }
              }
                   }
            `}
```

For example I want gameDate to remain constant, but stat could be any value of [MIN, FGA, FT, etc].

Answer (score 0):

Is it the input value $stat you talking about? or the response data?

If it is the response data(`stat`):

- Response data is resolved by the GraphQL server, so in order to change it, it should be the server responsibility to resolve `stat` according to the input data.

If it is the query `$stat`:

- Then you can define the query type as [Enum Type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#enumeration-types).

Comment: Not sure if I explained it right, as I'm brand new to graphQL.

I'd like to use $stat as a variable field in my query. Does this mean I need to write queries for every possible value that $stat could be?  I tried adding stat as a variable and using $stat in the query, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Okay, so in that case you need to update the GraphQL server to accept `stat` as input for the query. As I understand the query only has `condition` as variable (`allGamelogs(condition:$condition)`)